# UWP - Use assembly targeting .NET Framework 4.6

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to use a .NET Framework assembly in UWP (side loaded app). I know that it's not possible in any easy way, since UWP is targeting .NET Core.

I'm trying to create a Brokered Windows Runtime Component as explained in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps).

However I have issues:

- I can't use any templates from the market, because they are for Visual Studio 2015 and I'm using Visual Studio 2017
- I can't open the sample projects, because Visual Studio 2017 says that the projects (those with edited csproj files) are not compatible with that version of Visual Studio 2017
- The post-build script from that article uses `winmdidl` however it's not in my `PATH` so I have to put the full path `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\winmdidl"` (don't know if that's an issue)
- The `winmdidl` command returns an error `error W1005: Exception Unknown exception`

Additionally I have two questions:

- The samples and article uses a C++ "Proxy" project, can I just write the logic in C# in the brokered component without using any C++ code? (I just need to be able to call some methods from UWP which are defined in a 3rd party .NET assembly)
- Since the "Brokered Windows Runtime Component" method to call some code in .NET Framework seems cumbersome, maybe it's better to write some Windows Service or some other form of a REST service and communicate with it through `localhost`? That's a way I already use to communicate with some 3rd party tools on the machine. Is the performance and complexity in favor of the brokered component approach?

Comment: I've not tried it yet, but this could work. Create WPF application and use Desktop Bridge to convert the app to appx package. It will create solution where you have both, .net project (wpf) and uwp project. You should end up with simmilar solution like when using Brokered Windows Runtime Component.

Comment: But can this approach be used to reference .NET code from an existing UWP project? Will give it a try and update my question, thanks for the tip.

Comment: It looks like converting an existing C# UWP app to a "bridged app" isn't easy either, and would involve many changed to the app. So I guess a local REST service is still the easiest and robust way to do that communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Desktop Bridge features you not longer need the Windows Runtime Brokered Components. See this page for more information:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop

I guess this [sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample) using the AppService will help you to solve your scenario